# Why does python script randomly die on a Pi Zero?

Tags: python, mqtt

**Edit:**
For clarity:
The issue lies not within MQTT, but that the python script on the Pi Zero just dies. After some varying amount of time, the script stops existing and

```
sudo ps -ax | grep python
```

does not list the process running the script anymore.

**Original question:**

I wrote a simple script that reads a DHT22 sensor from a pi zero and publishes both temperature & humidity once a minute onto separate MQTT topics. At some point, the script just stops, as in it doesn't read nor publish any more readings, even though it runs in a while True loop. In my broker, the pi then shows as "Offline", as that is the last will message. The log files contain no useful information, in the sense, that as long as log files are written, the script works as intended and then there's suddenly a void.

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    message = "connected with rc: " + str(rc)
    print(message)
    log(message, mqtt_log_file)
    mqttPub.publish(topicStatusBedroom, "Online", 1, True)
def on_publish(client, obj, mid):
    message = "published with mid: " + str(mid)
    print(message)
    log(message, mqtt_log_file)
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("client disconnected ok")
    log("client disconnected\n", mqtt_log_file)
    while True:
        try:
            mqttPub.connect(url_str, url_port)
            break # break the while loop, if reconnect works
        except:
            time.sleep(2) # otherwise sleep and retry
def log(message, file):
    file = open(file, "a")
    file.write(message)
    file.close()  
mqttPub = mqtt.Client()
mqttPub.on_connect = on_connect
mqttPub.on_publish = on_publish
mqttPub.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
mqttPub.username_pw_set(username, givenPassword)
mqttPub.will_set(topicStatusBedroom, 'Offline', 1, True)
mqttPub.connect(url_str, url_port)
mqttPub.loop_start() # loop_start handles reconnects automatically

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pin = 22
    sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
    log_file = 'dht_22_logging.txt'

    while True:
        humidity, temperature = readDHT(sensor, pin)
        if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
            print('Temp={0:0.1f}*C  Humidity={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity))
            message = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") + "," + str(round(temperature, 1)) + "," + str(int(humidity)) + "\n"
            mqttPub.publish(topicStatusTemp, str(round(temperature, 1)), 1, True)
            mqttPub.publish(topicStatusHumidity, str(round(humidity, 0)), 1, True)
            log(message, log_file)    
        else:
            message = 'Failed to get reading. Try again!'
            print(message)
            log(message, log_file)
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: What's your `on_disconnect` implementation?

Comment: I've updated the post with the on_disconnect function. However, on_disconnect never gets called, as the message from print("client disconnected ok" never displays. All print messages also get saved to a logfile, and the print message also never appears in the log file, despite all other messages beeing saved in the log file.

Comment: What happened if you start it within `pdb` (the python debugger) ?

Comment: I used "sudo python3 -m pdb myscript.py" on Putty via SSH and it does not show any errors. At some point Putty closes the connection and it doesn't update the pdb messages anymore, nor does the script communicate. Does that mean, any scripts started via SSH are contained to that specific SSH session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**:
The script died with the SSH connection.
What worked was to create a service of the script and start it using systemd. I did follow this tutorial to get it working: 
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup/all

The script has been running for a week now without any problems.